# Explaination on the following line of code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, oop

I am learning Mongodb  and i am a litttle bit confuse on this line

```
mongoose.connection.once('open',function(){  
console.log('connection acquired harsh bajpai ');
}).on('error',function(error){ 
console.log('Connection error',error);});
```

what this line means does it means that when connection events occurs fire up this function once
but what does **.On** is doing there and can we do this with other events in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to the code below :

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    // we're connected!
});
```

Once the connection is established, the callback function will be called.
and if any error occurs while establishing the connnection, it will be displayed on console.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but can we use this format for some other events too such as onclick and onchange and if yes then how?

Comment: If your question is solved, please accept the answer (click the check mark underneath the down arrow).